# How to find out which https fields a server wants for a successful response?

Tags: php, api, email, https, client

Im currently in an internship and i want to build a android app thats capable of connecting to the companies email server.

But to be able to connect a device to the server i need to know which fields the server expects inside a clients https request in addition to working user/pass credentials.

I tried getting informations about the packets sent with tcpdumb (server and client side) and wireshark, but they seem to be encrypted or not readable, which makes sense considering it's https.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Roundcube Webmail :: Willkommen bei Roundcube Webmail</title>
<meta name="Robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
<link rel="index" href="./?_task=login" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="skins/classic/images/favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skins/classic/common.min.css?s=1418906028" />

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/jqueryui/themes/classic/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css?s=1418906027">
<script src="program/js/jquery.min.js?s=1418906027" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="program/js/common.min.js?s=1418906027" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="program/js/app.min.js?s=1418906027" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="program/js/jstz.min.js?s=1418906027" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

var rcmail = new rcube_webmail();
rcmail.set_env({"task":"login","x_frame_options":"sameorigin","standard_windows":false,"cookie_domain":"","cookie_path":"\/","cookie_secure":true,"skin":"classic","refresh_interval":60,"session_lifetime":600,"action":"","comm_path":".\/?_task=login","compose_extwin":false,"date_format":"yy-mm-dd","request_token":"029873c7042111df50bf712676a72046"});
rcmail.gui_container("loginfooter","bottomline");
rcmail.add_label({"loading":"Wird geladen...","servererror":"Serverfehler!","connerror":"Verbindungsfehler (Fehler beim Erreichen des Servers)!","requesttimedout":"Zeit\u00fcberschreitung der Anforderung","refreshing":"Aktualisieren\u2026"});
rcmail.gui_object('message', 'message');
rcmail.gui_object('loginform', 'form');
/* ]]> */
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js?s=1418906027"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqueryui/js/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-de.js?s=1418906027"></script>
</head>
<body>

<img src="skins/classic/images/roundcube_logo.png" id="logo" border="0" style="margin:0 11px" alt="Roundcube Webmail">

<div id="message"></div>

<div id="login-form">
<div class="boxtitle">Willkommen bei Roundcube Webmail</div>
<div class="boxcontent">

<form name="form" method="post" action="./?_task=login">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="029873c7042111df50bf712676a72046">
<input type="hidden" name="_task" value="login"><input type="hidden" name="_action" value="login"><input type="hidden" name="_timezone" id="rcmlogintz" value="_default_"><input type="hidden" name="_url" id="rcmloginurl" value=""><table summary="" border="0"><tbody><tr><td class="title"><label for="rcmloginuser">Benutzername</label>
</td>
<td class="input"><input name="_user" id="rcmloginuser" required="required" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="title"><label for="rcmloginpwd">Passwort</label>
</td>
<td class="input"><input name="_pass" id="rcmloginpwd" required="required" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" type="password"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="formbuttons"><input type="submit" id="rcmloginsubmit" class="button mainaction" value="Anmelden"></p>

</form>

</div>
</div>

<noscript>
  <p id="login-noscriptwarning">Warnung: Dieser Webmail-Service erfordert Javascript. Um ihn zu benutzten aktivieren Sie Javascript in ihren Browser-Einstellungen.</p>
</noscript>

<div id="login-bottomline">
  Roundcube Webmail 

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

$(document).ready(function(){ 
rcmail.init();
var images = ["skins\/classic\/images\/icons\/folders.png","skins\/classic\/images\/mail_footer.png","skins\/classic\/images\/taskicons.gif","skins\/classic\/images\/display\/loading.gif","skins\/classic\/images\/pagenav.gif","skins\/classic\/images\/mail_toolbar.png","skins\/classic\/images\/searchfield.gif","skins\/classic\/images\/messageicons.png","skins\/classic\/images\/icons\/reset.gif","skins\/classic\/images\/abook_toolbar.png","skins\/classic\/images\/icons\/groupactions.png","skins\/classic\/images\/watermark.gif"];
            for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
                img = new Image();
                img.src = images[i];
            }
});
/* ]]> */
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code from the clients login page, is there a way i can come up with what the server wants based on this code? 
I have no experience with php whatsover but i built a rest api + client in java last semester.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See all the `<input>` elements in the `<form>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried getting informations about the packets sent with tcpdumb (server and client side) and wireshark, but they seem to be encrypted or not readable, which makes sense considering it's https.

Use the developer tools in the browser. They allow you to inspect requests before they go into the encrypted tunnel.

> This is the code from the clients login page, is there a way i can come up with what the server wants based on this code?

Maybe.

The form's fields (inputs, selects, buttons, and textareas) will tell you what data is submitted if the server uses a regular form submission. The name attributes tell you the field name.

It is possible that the JavaScript in the page modifies the form when the submit event fires though.

> i want to build a android app thats capable of connecting to the companies email server.

That HTML shows that you are trying to access Roundmail. Last time I checked, that was a web app that just talks to an IMAP backend.

IMAP is a well documented and standard mailbox protocol with plenty of libraries available to work with it. You would be *far* better off just using it instead of trying to screen scrape a webmail front end.

Comment: Thank you, didnt know about the inspector! 
Im going to take your advice and look into IMAP, im pretty new when it comes to work with anything else than http APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Just submit form and then check what was sent to server (use the inspector for that)

Comment: Thank you, didnt know about the inspector!